# Is there a simple way to send a single message synchronously to discord?

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, message, synchronous

I am working on a program that periodically posts messages to my discord channel. As posting to discord is not the primary function of the program, I have written the program synchronously, so I am having trouble interacting with the asynchronous discord.py API.

Thus far, the best I have been able to do is the following:

```
import discord
import asyncio

discord_token = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456"
discord_channel_ids = { 'test_channel': 012345678901234567 }

async def send_msg_async(client, channel_ids, message):
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    for cid in channel_ids:
        channel = client.get_channel(cid)
        await channel.send(message)
    await client.logout()

def send_message(channel_names, message):
    try:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        client = discord.Client(loop=loop)

        channel_ids = [discord_channel_ids[cname] for cname in channel_names]
        client.loop.create_task(send_msg_async(client, channel_ids, message))
        client.run(discord_token)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception sending message to discord: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_message(["test_channel"], "This is a test.")
```

The above essentially creates a new event loop, logs in, sends the message, logs out, and then closes the event loop. However, it is highly unstable, and it takes 5-6 seconds to perform the desired task (by far the most expensive operation is the client.wait_until_ready(), which logs in to discord). I am wondering whether there is a better way to do this, aside from just rewriting my entire program to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do *something* every *n* time, the discord extension library provides **tasks** that run asynchronously.

Example:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

client = commands.Bot()

@tasks.loop(seconds=15.0)
async def my_task():
    print('I am a task, hello')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  my_task.start()
```

Comment: The issue is that when my program is not posting to discord (which it only does once or twice an hour), it is performing other, synchronous tasks. So unless this was performed in another thread (which I would rather not have to do), the other program tasks would block it. Ideally, I feel like there should be a way to synchronously just tell the program "send this status update to discord" without having to keep a loop going nonstop.

Comment: Tasks is asynchronously, I can't see the problem here.

Comment: @Verify OP is talking about _synchronous_ code, not the opposite _asynchronous_ code.